# When sharing an album on Facebook, why is the number of photos different for me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

On another Facebook account that I see in my timeline, there was posted a photo album.  It's displaying in their timeline as the first 4 photos, and "+10" over the 5th photo.  When I click any of the photos here, and step through them, there's clearly 14 (or maybe 15) photos in the loop.

I want to share this album on my timeline, so I chose "Share...", but in the preview window that appears, the 5th photo is different, and it has the number "+100" over it.  The text from the post is gone.

(When I click on the album name at the top of the post, it takes me to an album page, which clearly has 100+ photos in it.)

Is there any way to share just the 14 that are in the album on this other person's timeline?  I don't want to share a giant 100+ photo album.  I don't understand why there's a small album and a big album, but I just want the small one.

Comment: Its a bit unclear to me. What is small album and big album? There is no small or big album on Facebook.

Comment: serenesat: Small album = version with 14 photos, big album = version with 100+ photos.

Comment: I figured out that the small album is the subset of the album in which I'm tagged in a photo.  I still haven't figured out a way to share just this subset, or even the text of the post.  Even though it appears in my timeline as text + 14 photos, the only way I can share it is as the 100+ photo album, and without the original text.